# Does the file size of a compressed jpg affect memory footprint in the browser?

Tags: performance, compression, browser, jpeg

Lossy compression with JPGs can have a drastic effect on the size of an image "over the wire", but does that affect how much memory is used when displaying the image in a web browser?

Suppose I have 2 versions of the same 1500x600px image. One is full quality, uncompressed, and is 2mb. The other is saved for web in Photoshop and is 50kb. Does the more compressed image take up less memory when being displayed, and if so is it significant?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does compressing an image make the image use less memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353661/does-compressing-an-image-make-the-image-use-less-memory)

Answer (score 1):

No. The amount of compression does not affect the amount of memory needed to display the image. The uncompressed size is the same.